# Clojure-esque threading macro?

Tags: macros, julia

How to implement, or is there an implementation of [Clojure-like threading macros](https://clojure.org/guides/threading_macros), namely thread-first (`->`) and thread-last (`->>`)?

Example:

```
# equivalent of sum(1, 2)
@thread-first 1 sum(2)

# equivalent of any(map(isequal(1), [1,2,3]))
@thread-last [1,2,3] map(isequal(1)) any
```

Comment: you can get updated info [in this Julia github issue / discussion](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/24990) regarding "piping" (another name for what you want).

Comment: Another keyword for this feature is "currying"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julia has pipelining, but in general the |> operator only allows one-argument functions.  In Clojure, the thread-first and thread-last arguments insert the argument at the beginning or end of multiple arguments in the function.

You do have the @> and @>> macros in Lazy.jl:

https://github.com/MikeInnes/Lazy.jl#macros

These do thread-first and thread-last, but with different syntax.  See the Lazy.jl docs. Example of thread-last:

```
 @>> 1:10 collect filter(isodd) square.() reduce(+)
 165
```

example of thread-first:

```
@> 6 div(2)
3
```